# Angular component binding at construction

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component :

```
import template from './login.html';
import controller from './login.controller';
import './login.less';

let loginComponent = {
  restrict: 'E',
  bindings: {
    redirect: '@'
  },
  template,
  controller,
  controllerAs: 'vm'
};

export default loginComponent;
```

Which uses a basic controller:

```
import angular from 'angular';

let LoginController = [
    'AuthService',
    '$resource',
    '$state',
    'config',
    (AuthService, $resource, $state, config) => {
        var vm = {
            redirect: ''
        };

        var initialize = () => {
            if (AuthService.authenticated()) {
                loginSuccess();
            }
        };

        var loginSuccess = () => {
            console.log(vm.redirect);
            if (vm.redirect) {
                $state.go(vm.redirect);
            }
        };

        initialize();
        return vm;
    },
];

export default LoginController;
```

The issue is that the `redirect` attribute is not available at the time of construction (when the `initialize` method is called).  How do I access this attribute during controller construction?  If there is no way, what's the best way to watching for this attribute to become available, and then calling the `initialize` function?

---

### Solution:

`$onInit` was exactly the method I was looking for.  Here's the corrected controller for future users:

```
import angular from 'angular';

let LoginController = [
    'AuthService',
    '$resource',
    '$state',
    'config',
    (AuthService, $resource, $state, config) => {
        var vm = {
            redirect: ''
        };

        vm.$onInit = () => {
            if (AuthService.authenticated()) {
                loginSuccess();
            }
        };

        var loginSuccess = () => {
            console.log(vm.redirect);
            if (vm.redirect) {
                $state.go(vm.redirect);
            }
        };

        return vm;
    },
];

export default LoginController;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the binding at controller construction because of how Angular directive linking works.

It will be available in `link` function in directive, in component (which is sugar syntax for directive) it is available in magic [`$onInit` controller method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-):

> Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have
>   been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the
>   pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This
>   is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

The problem with listed controller is that it uses arrow function instead of regular one. The controller is an instance of controller constructor and provides `this` context.

There is no need to invent `initialize` method, it should be `this.$onInit` now.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thanks a ton.